# How effective is the individual conversion of view controllers to ARC?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I am not using ARC for the whole application.But in some view controllers I am using it by the compler flag `-fobjc-arc`. I don't know how it will work, and also pros and cons of that, is that a good technique? is there any adverse effect on doing like this?. Can any body has this experience?. can anybody help me?. Also I am using Xcode 4.2 and LLVM compiler3.0.It is actually a non arc view controller.But i added the copiler flag.and removed compiled errors of releases.is that enough

Comment: ARC help you to write less code. It can improve performance, but you should really not count  on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However i found this to be extremely tricky and find this article is a well written example for my cause.http://www.codeography.com/2011/10/10/making-arc-and-non-arc-play-nice.html

Answer (score 2):

You will typically want to approach this process using the refactoring utility Xcode provides: `Edit > Refactor > Convert to Objective-C ARC…`.

MRC and ARC binaries are able to work together seamlessly. They are compatible.

Of course, you need to ensure your programs are correctly for the mode they are being compiled. The static analyzer will give some hints if the flag is wrong and you have omitted reference count operations -- or the compiler will error when it sees a reference count operation. As usual, check for leaks at compile-time and runtime to find what your eyes missed.

The execution speeds may vary slightly (either could be faster/slower). The memory high water points will probably vary a little. ARC programs are generally equivalent to well written MRC.

Comment: @justin..thanks for ur attention. I really mean that i just added -fobjc-arc in the compile source.then when i compiled some errors come as that of releases and so and so.then i removed all the autoreleases and releases.then that errors gone.i am really a newbee in arc.is that enough

Comment: @hacker you're welcome. Automated conversion to ARC is usually correct, but it is not perfect. Real programs are just too complex. So the automated process is pretty straightforward and does the right thing most of the time. However, it can introduce some changes, and you will need to reserve time to re-test your programs (and make any necessary repairs). For a lot of programs out there, the conversion process could still result in a reduction in bug count.

Comment: @hacker you are using the automated conversion, right? `Edit > Refactor > Convert to ObjC ARC…`

Comment: i just added -fobjc-arc in the compile source.is there anything needs to change in the settings.compiler is LLVM3.0

Comment: @hacker a) make sure you are using version control (e.g. Git) or work on a copy, then b) use the refactoring tool i have mentioned instead. c) then test

Comment: i am using using a new -fobjc-arc compiler flag for some reasons because i need this only in some controllers.thats why i have these doubts,

Comment: @hacker the compiler needs very strict semantics for ARC to work -- it will flag the majority of the issues for you, in the even you don't use the convertor.

Answer (score 2):

There will be no issues with this approach.

ARC is a compile-time feature, it'll insert retain, release calls in your arc code at the compile time.

So your arc code will be same as your non-arc code after compilation. So I think there will be no issues with this approach.

But converting the entire project to ARC will be the best approach, because you don't need to worry about the retain, release calls

Comment: @mdhun..thanks for ur attention. I really mean that i just added -fobjc-arc in the compile source.then when i compiled some errors come as that of releases and so and so.then i removed all the autoreleases and releases.then that errors gone.i am really a newbee in arc.is that enough...now i have no releases in that view controllers..analyser is showing no leaks in the view controllers..

Comment: I'm total agreement with @Midhum, if you want to know a bit more about how ARC works take a look to the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @hacker: No need of worrying. When you are converting non-arc to arc, remove release, retain and autorelease. If you need to add a task in autoreleasepool. You can use `@autorelease` keyword.

Comment: i have the worry that if just adding the copiler flag and removing the releases will do the trick?